# Создание очереди в с++

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста, я только начал изучать с++ и не совсем понимаю, как сделать эту задачу. Понятного материала для меня я не нашел(( Прошу не бросаться калом, я всего лишь учусь(
Суть задачи.

Записать введенные с клавиатуры числа с плавающей запятой в очередь. Вывести очередь на экран. Удалить их последовательно из очереди и вывести на экран, если соответствующий элемент - положительное число.

Если проще будет без вывода всей очереди, то пусть будет так. Спасибо за понимание, надеюсь на помощь)

Comment: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue Удачи в изучении!

Comment: @Harry, спасибо за самую лучшую помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://youtu.be/U4mV_MVCLuU

вот это оочень хороший канал по с++. в этом видео реализаци очереди в stl рассматривается. Если только начинаешь - канал советую всеми руками